# Make header fit in div and not scroll with content

Tags: css, scroll, css-position

I'm trying to create a header that:

1. has a width that is 100% of it's parent div (which will not be the total width of the window); and
2. stay in the same position relative to the viewport when scrolling.

I've looked for answers on this but all focus on creating a fixed header when the header is 100% of the window width. My div is not that wide. Here is a snippet:

```css
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #EEE;
  line-height: 35px;
}

#first_item {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.item {
  height: 85px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #BBDDEF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Header that shouldn't scroll or overlap scrollbar</div>
  <div class="item" id="first_item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Notice that the header respects the scrollbar on the far right - I need the header to respect the scrollbar of its parent (the one in the middle).

Answer (score 0):

Try using {position:sticky} rather than fixed in #header css

You can refer here to know the difference : https://www.kevinpowell.co/article/positition-fixed-vs-sticky/

Comment: sticky has really bad compatibility

Comment: Agreed. You can refer this then :https://css-tricks.com/stickybits-alternative-position-sticky-polyfills/#:~:text=Stickybits%20a%20lightweight%20(~2KB,plugins%2C%20libraries%2C%20or%20frameworks.

Comment: Or this might help : https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sticky-positioning-with-nothing-but-css--cms-24042

Answer (score 0):

If you give a transform to the wrapper it will create its own sort of viewport. The fixed div will take on 100% of the wrapper width and it will stay fixed within this wrapper so you get what you require.

Turns out it isn’t necessary to actually transform the wrapper. will-change is enough to create this new context.

```css
#wrapper {
  will-change: transform;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #BBB;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #EEE;
  line-height: 35px;
}

#first_item {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.item {
  height: 85px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #BBDDEF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">Header that shouldn't scroll or overlap scrollbar</div>
  <div class="item" id="first_item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
</div>
```